# jQuery: Get or alert the number that contains letter

Tags: jquery

I'd like to get a result of: E1,E5. Is this possible in jQuery or even in PHP?

**UPDATED:**

I'd like to apply it ton my json_encoded data. the

```
var array = $('#lot_numbers').val(details.lot_number);
```

has a data which is **E1,1,2,3,4,5,E5**

```
$('#end_unit').change(function() {
    if($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $('#display_lot_numbers').hide('slow');
    } else {

        if($(this).val() == 'Yes') {

        var allotment_code = $('#allotment_code').val();

        $.post(base_url('ajax/ajaxGetUnits.php'), {
            allotment_code:allotment_code
        },
        function(data, status) {

            var details = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#display_lot_numbers').show('slow');

            var array = $('#lot_numbers').val(details.lot_number);

            var nonnumbers = $.grep(array.split(","), function(n, i) {
                return isNaN(n);
            }).join(",");

            console.log(nonnumbers);
        });

        }
    }
})
```

Comment: upvote for this?

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: I'd like to apply it to my data which is from json_encode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

First split the string and make an array and then use `grep` method to get non numbers by using `isNaN` function.

```js
var lot_numbers = 'E1,1,2,3,4,5,E5';
var nonnumbers = $.grep(lot_numbers.split(","), function(n, i) {
  return isNaN(n);
}).join(",");

console.log(nonnumbers);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: most authenticated answer.+1

Comment: Hi. thanks for the answer. I tried to apply it to my data from JSON that I parsed and it didn't work though. is there a way to make it work?

Comment: for JSON, as per its structure you need to change the condition in `grep` function! share you JSON structure.

Comment: also change your line `var array = $('#lot_numbers').val(details.lot_number);
` to `var array = $('#lot_numbers').val(details.lot_number).val();`

Answer (score 0):

Without even using jQuery - just regular js:

```
    var lot_numbers = 'E1,1,2,3,4,5,E5';
    var arr = lot_numbers.split(",");
    var result = arr.filter(function(i) {
       return i.match(/[a-z]/i); 
    });
    return result.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```js
var lot_numbers = 'E1,1,2,3,4,5,E5';
var arr = lot_numbers.split(',');
var patt = /[a-zA-Z]\d/;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (patt.test(arr[i])) {
    alert(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Check below solution.
```

```js
var lot_numbers = 'E1,1,2,3,4,5,E5';
var array=lot_numbers.split(",");

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   // Check number or not
   if(isNaN(array[i]))
    alert(array[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of jQuery, plain javascript will help.

```
var lot_numbers = 'E1,1,2,3,4,5,E5';
var arr = lot_numbers.split(",");

var alphanum = arr.filter(function(x) {
  return isNaN(x);
}).join();

console.log(alphanum);   // "E1,E5"
```

Comment: how can I apply this with JSON.parse? I have parsed my data.